# android: how to disable action mode when a user long click on a web view?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-actionbar, android-webview

How can I disable the action mode. In another word, I want to prevent the action mode from appearing when the user long clicks on a web view that contains a text.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't worked a lot with `WebViews` in general, but I think one of these should work. I haven't tested any of these though.

1:

Set the attribute on the `WebView` in the XML: `android:longClickable="false"`

Or 2:

Set the above attribute in Java instead of XML:

```
your_webview.setLongClickable(false);
```

Or 3: Override your `WebView` and `return true` in the `setOnLongClickListener` method

```
your_webview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you my dear and i really appreciate your answer :)
but note that i already use the setOnLongClick method so i tried the 3rd solution and its solve my problem. Thank you once again :)

Comment: @KhalidMohamedElSayed: I'm glad to have helped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding below line to view had worked. We will be consuming long click listener.

```
view.setOnLongClickListener { true }
```